# rxjs operator that will make http call but will ignore the data and will not return an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I would like to make a HTTP call and get the output as observable (this is the easy part) and then, immediately make another HTTP call and ignore the output.

I can not use switchMap operator because the second HTTP call does not return something useful. it just returns 'Done!' and the first call returns complex JSON that i need.

what I did, and it works, is to subscribe to the inner http call and i would like to know if there is an rxjs operator that i can use instead:

```
this.dataStorageBaseService.createIdentity(identity)
  .do(() => this.authService.JustSimpleHTTPCall().first().subscribe()).subscribe();
```

Is there a RxJS operator that i can use instead of subscribe again to the "JustSimpleHTTPCall"? map would be good but i do not need the data that JustSimpleHTTPCall returns and it will not work together with the output of "createIdentity" that I need to return as observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need your inner Observable to emit the outer result - this can be done with [concat](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concat)

```
this.dataStorageBaseService.createIdentity(identity)
  .switchMap(result => this.authService.JustSimpleHTTPCall().concat(Observable.of(result)))
  .subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
this.dataStorageBaseService.createIdentity(identity)
  .concatMap(result => this.authService.JustSimpleHTTPCall()
    .map(() => result) // ignore the second response and use the first one instead
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Are you sure that concatMap doesn't need to return that same structure as the map operator? the output of both of the HTTP Calls are not the same....

Comment: What structure? The callback just needs to return an Observable which it does. (note that `.map()` returns Observable)